# How to execute a function defined in a controller attached to a previous page after ons.navigator.popPage() ?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, onsen-ui

I discover Onsen UI and I have a problem :

1- I defined 2 pages `page-1.html` and `page-2.html` with a controller attached (`page1Ctrl` and `page2Ctrl`).

2- I defined a function in page1Ctrl to go to the page-2.html :

```
$scope.ons.navigator.pushPage('page-2.html');
```

which executes `page2Ctrl`

3- In this page, i have a button which executes a code that returns on `page-1.html` (with `popPage()`). This function is attached to `page2Ctrl` :

```
function page2Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.functionToPopPage = function() {

        // >>> Here I would like to execute a function attached to page1Ctrl

        $scope.ons.navigator.popPage();
    };
}
```

4- then, i want to launch a function defined in the `page1Ctrl`, **how could i process it ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can share controller's function with service. Try to register the function you want to attache to both page1Ctrl and page2Ctrl, then call the shared function from page2Ctrl. The following code is a example.

page1.html

```
<ons-page class="center" ng-controller="page1Ctrl">
  <ons-navigator-toolbar
    title="Welcome">        
  </ons-navigator-toolbar>
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
  <ons-button ng-click="goToPage2()">Push Page 2</ons-sbutton>  
</ons-page>
```

page2.html

```
<ons-page class="center" ng-controller="page2Ctrl">
  <ons-navigator-toolbar title="Page 2">        
  </ons-navigator-toolbar>
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
  <button class="topcoat-button" ng-click="popToPage1()">Pop Page1</button>
</ons-page>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen.directives']);


myApp.factory('pageService', function(){
    return{
        foo : function()
            alert('foo');
        }
    }        
});

myApp.controller('page1Ctrl', function($scope, pageService){    
    $scope.goToPage2 = function(){
        pageService.foo();
        $scope.ons.navigator.pushPage("page2.html");        
    }
});

myApp.controller('page2Ctrl', function($scope, pageService){    
    $scope.popToPage1 = function(){
        pageService.foo();
        $scope.ons.navigator.popPage();        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

idea:

- You declare a global variable
- In the controller you page1Ctrl assigns your function to this variable
- And you used in page2Ctrl :)

ex :

```
var heloWord;

function page1Ctrl($scope) {
  heloWord = function() {
    console.log('Helo Word');
  }
}

function page2Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.functionToPopPage = function() {
    heloWord();
    $scope.ons.navigator.popPage();
  };
}
```